# C: Problems with preprocessing definition

Tags: c

I see the following error when compiling...

```
./src/gettext.h:17:22: fatal error: libintl.h: No such file or directory
```

So I look at the code and see...

```
#ifndef NO_GETTEXT
#       include <libintl.h>
#else
#       ifdef gettext
#               undef gettext
#       endif
#       define gettext(s) (s)
#       ifdef ngettext
#               undef ngettext
#       endif
#       define ngettext(s, p, n) ((n == 1) ? (s) : (p))
#endif
```

I add a file called config.h which I add the following....

```
#define NO_GETTEXT
```

But it doesn't seem to have defined it because I still see the error. I am rather new to C so I am not sure what is up. Any help?

Comment: Are you using pre-compiled headers? It's possible the compiler will have processed config.h and saved a partially-compiled version of it to use in future and so not noticed your change.

Comment: are you shure that your compiler got a path to the `libintl.h` file?
maybe the (i guess postgres) `include` directory is not known by your environment

Comment: When you define `NO_GETTEXT` in `config.h`, have you done `#include "config.h"` before the code above?

Comment: +Neil Townsend You were pretty much right on, but instead of changing the code I added the CFlag below. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops should be...

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DNO_GETTEXT
```

in my MakeFile